# Simple Cypher query percent calcul in

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have many Products and want to know how many percent are valid,
I am new in Cypher and trying to use `WITH keyword` without success :

```
MATCH (n:ratedItem) 
WHERE n.idCategory = "45" AND 
  n.isValidate = "1" AND 
  n.value_fr = 1 
WITH count(n) as totalValidate 
MATCH (n:ratedItem) 
WHERE n.idCategory = "45" 
WITH count(n) as total 
RETURN (totalValidate / total) * 100
```

I have a syntax error, it seems that Cypher doesn't know the 1st count `totalValidate`

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten it on the second `WITH` :

```
MATCH (n:ratedItem) 
WHERE n.idCategory = "45" AND 
  n.isValidate = "1" AND 
  n.value_fr = 1 
WITH count(n) as totalValidate 
MATCH (n:ratedItem) 
WHERE n.idCategory = "45" 
WITH count(n) as total, totalValidate
RETURN (totalValidate / total) * 100
```